# Capistrano symlink database.yml task error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano

I'm running a Rails 3.2.x app with Capistrano 2.12.0.  I've pulled my database.yml out of github/version control and manually placed a copy under `/home/deploy/myapp/shared/config/database.yml`

I'm trying to get my `deploy.rb` to symlink this file using `before:assets:precompile` so that the file is symlinked in the release directory and the deployment can continue.  Here is the error I get:

```
/Users/james/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:103:in `on': please specify either a task name or a block to invoke (ArgumentError)
```

Here is what my deploy.rb looks like:

**deploy.rb**

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"
require "whenever/capistrano"
set :shared_children, shared_children + %w{public/uploads}
server "72.14.181.22", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application, "myapp"
set :user, "deploy"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/#{application}"
#set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false
set :rails_env, "production"


set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "git@github.com:james/#{application}.git"
set :branch, "master"


default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases
after "deploy:update"
before "deploy:assets:precompile", "config_symlink"

namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
  desc "reload the database with seed data"
  task :seed do
    run "cd #{current_path}; bundle exec rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
  end
end

task :config_symlink do
  run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
end
```

Basically what I need to do is symlink the /home/deploy/myapp/shared/config/database.yml to /home/deploy/myapp/current/config/database.yml before the assets precompile so the database can be accessed.

I'm sure I have some sort of syntax error here but could really use some help.  I want to keep my `database.yml` out of version control, leave it in the myapp/shared/config directly and symlink it on deploy for security purposes.

For the longest time I thought I had been doing this, but apparently I hadn't so I need to figure this out.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I don't want to have to resort to keeping `database.yml` in github/version control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got this working.  It looks like in my original deploy.rb I was calling `after "deploy:update"` but wasn't passing anything to the callback so it was bombing on me.  I've cleaned up my deploy.rb file and have tested deployment to a staging server and it seems to work.

**deploy.rb updated**

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"
require "whenever/capistrano"
set :shared_children, shared_children + %w{public/uploads}
server "72.14.181.11", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application, "myapp"
set :user, "deploy"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/#{application}"
#set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false
set :rails_env, "production"


set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "git@github.com:james/#{application}.git"
set :branch, "master"


default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

before "deploy:assets:precompile", "config_symlink"
after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases

namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
  desc "reload the database with seed data"
  task :seed do
    run "cd #{current_path}; bundle exec rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
  end
end

task :config_symlink do
  run "ln -nfs #{deploy_to}/shared/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
end
```